How to remove line break in text area field using a formula field?
I have a requirement where I need to remove the line breaks in a text area field before processing it further. I'm using a formula field to do so.
I tried using this formula but its not working. Any other suggestions?
SUBSTITUTE({!BillingAddress.Street}, "\n", "")


Try SUBSTITUTE({!ServiceAppointment.Street}, BR(), "") SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE({!ServiceAppointment.Street}, BR(), ""), "\r", "")

Both the options are not working.
